# Удаление записей из БД (SQLite) по элементам в spinner'e

Tags: android, android-spinner, sqlite

Доброго времени суток!

Пишу приложение. Во фрагменте нужно выводить записи из колонки таблицы БД в спиннер (Spinner). Также добавляю записи в эту таблицу с автообновлением спинера. Все это работает. 
Но встал вопрос удаления и корректировки записей в БД по требованию.

К примеру, в БД и соответственно в спинере есть 5 записей. 2-ю запись в спинере (#1) нужно обновить. Я выбираю эту запись, жму кнопку и через AlertDialog ввожу и записываю новые значения. Данный пример работает, если обращаться по _id в таблице, но записи же могут  быть удалены пользователем. Поэтому _id будут такими: 1,2, 4, 6 и так далее. То есть будут пропуски, что не даст возможности корректной работы изменения по id в спинере.

Как решить данный вопрос, чтобы по выбранному элементу в спинере был отредактирован или удален элемент в таблице БД? Первые шаги я сделал - получил String значение элемента в спинере. Далее все по коду ниже.

```
public void onClick_NewTow_EditButton() {
/* 1. Получить значение со spiner'a */
String spinSelectedItem = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
Integer spinSelectedItemId = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() + 1;
Log.v(LOG_TAG, "select: " + spinSelectedItem + '\n' + "selectItemPos: "
        + spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(DataBaseClass.TOW_COL_PR, 12);
values.put(DataBaseClass.TOW_COL_TOW, "проверка2");

sqdb.update(DataBaseClass.TOW_PRICE_TABLE, values,
        DataBaseClass.TOW_COL_ID + " = ?",
        new String[]{String.valueOf(spinSelectedItemId)});

spinnerUpdateMethode(); // Это мой собственный метод, который обновляет список в спинере.
```

По нему вопросов нет, работает хорошо.

В итоге это работает как-то криво - обновляется не та запись.

P.S.: сделал также сортировку в спинере. Сортирую в курсоре, а потом через ArrayAdapter в spinner.

Comment: Ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста, с данными уроками: [раз](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/111-urok-52-simplecursoradapter-primer-ispolzovanija), 
[два](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/278-urok-136-cursorloader.html).

Comment: Нашел способ решения своего вопроса. Нужно было изменить запрос на следующий:

sqdb.update(DataBaseClass.TOW_PRICE_TABLE, values, DataBaseClass.TOW_COL_TOW + " like ?", new String[] { spinSelectedItem });

Comment: А для удаления записей следует использовать такой код:

sqdb.delete(DataBaseClass.TOW_PRICE_TABLE, DataBaseClass.TOW_COL_TOW + " like ?", new String[] { spinSelectedItem });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через большой промежуток времени решил оформить ответ на свой вопрос. Считаю, что это поможет пользователям в будущим, т.к. видно, что ответ есть.

```
sqdb.delete(DataBaseClass.TOW_PRICE_TABLE, DataBaseClass.TOW_COL_TOW + " like ?", new String[] { spinSelectedItem });
```

// `spinSelectedItem` - строковое значение того, что было показано в `spinner`'e.